# Ignore two parameters from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my logs method I want to implement some kind of mechanism which ignore two parameters `created_at` and `updated_at` (in other place it will be e.g. password) from `new_data: form`. `form` is a hash of admin parameters - `AdminUser.new(form)` (like email, name, password etc.)

Method below:

```
def log_admin_data
  admin_user = AdminUser.last
  AdminPanelLog.update(
    admin_email: admin_user.email,
    admin_role: admin_user.role,
    type: 'Create new Admin User',
    new_data: form, #some kind of method like ignore_attribute(created_at, updated_at)
  )
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#except`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)

```
form.except('created_at', 'updated_at')
```